# Evaluating Logical Operations AND, OR, NOT dynamically in Java

Tags: java, parsing, logical-operators, recursive-descent

I have a requirement to execute dynamic expressions for the input data (Map) using Java Code.
For Example,

**Condition** -

```
EmployeeShift = 'General' AND (EmployeeType = 'CONTRACT' OR Designation IN 'ADMIN')
```

This expression will be passed on as string variable and with this I have to evaluate my input data which comes at run time. So I'm looking for a parser to parse the condition.

Using the answer of **@Tagir Valeev** from  - [the stack over flow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193036/resolving-logical-operations-and-or-looping-conditions-dynamically) I was able to parse AND, OR operations. But I'm not sure how to extend it for NOT operation. I'm expecting something to work like below where the expression checks for combined NOT operation for EmployeeType and Designation, rather than checking for each variable.

```
EmployeeShift = 'General' AND NOT(EmployeeType = 'CONTRACT' OR Designation IN 'ADMIN')
```

Any example or leads on how to do will be of huge help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Whenever I do parsing I've got to the point where I want something industrial strength and so go to [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) to generate my parser and they have lots of grammar examples, e.g. [arithmetic](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4) and a [query language](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cql/cql.g4)

Comment: Maybe a rules engine with parsing abilities

Comment: This is what `java.util.function.Predicate` is for, or at least one of the things.

Comment: @scrhartley Will it be possible to provide an example for the mentioned scenario. I see the examples you shared but I'm not sure how to implement it. It's bit confusing

Comment: ANTLR is all about trying to get you to buy [the book](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/). However, you can scrape enough information with Google: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example), [SO showing Visitor use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092081/antlr4-visitor-pattern-on-simple-arithmetic-example), [an article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-antlr). Generally, you use a parse tree to make a more useful version, the AST ([Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Especially a wheel that could be quite complex. What you need is a rules engine like [easy-rules](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules) (as one example)