# ANTLR Evaluating Logical Operations AND, OR, NOT dynamically in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I have a requirement to execute dynamic expressions for the input data (Map) using Java Code. For Example,

**Condition -**

```
EmployeeShift = 'General' AND (EmployeeType = 'CONTRACT' OR Designation IN 'ADMIN')
```

This expression will be passed on as string variable and with this I have to evaluate my input data which comes at run time. So I'm looking for a parser to parse the condition.

Using the answer of @TagirValeev from - [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193036/resolving-logical-operations-and-or-looping-conditions-dynamically) I was able to parse AND, OR operations. But I'm not sure how to extend it for NOT operation. I'm expecting something to work like below where the expression checks for combined NOT operation for EmployeeType and Designation, rather than checking for each variable.

```
EmployeeShift = 'General' AND NOT(EmployeeType = 'CONTRACT' OR Designation IN 'ADMIN')
```

```
if(EmployeeShift = 'General' && !(EmployeeType = 'CONTRACT' || Designation IN 'ADMIN'))
```

I tried checking from native Java Code but none worked so decided to use ANTLR if any one can help me with some example for the above condition it will be of huge help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have an ANTLR related question, please add your ANTLR grammar (and re-tag your question with antlr tags)

Comment: I would like to know whether the above mentioned condition is possible to parse in ANTLR and I would like to have a sample grammar file which can satisfy it.

Comment: Yes, that can easily be done with ANTLR. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976962/nested-boolean-expression-parser-using-antlr You only need some small changes to get it working. Try it yourself first, study how things work with ANTLR by reading some tutorials. And ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bart Kiers. I was able to do most of the conditions which I wanted. I would like to do with some string functions like CONTAINS and STARTS WITH can you give a sample for that?

Comment: Try it yourself first, study how things work with ANTLR by reading some tutorials. And ask specific questions if you get stuck by creating a new question. These comment boxes are ill suited for Q&A's.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77106698/antlr-accepting-special-characters-like-dot-and-comma-in-identifier-or-e