# ANTLR accepting special characters like . (dot) and , (comma) in identifier or expression

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I'm trying to execute dynamic expressions for the input data (Map) using ANTLR and using the answer of @Bart Kiers from the [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976962/nested-boolean-expression-parser-using-antlr) I was able to do it.

I tried to add `IN`, `STARTSWITH`, `ENDSWITH` condition with in the grammer and trying to add the logic for it from the java end. For the case of `IN` function I'm trying to split a set of string using a special character preferably `, (comma)`. But when I add them in my expression I get an error as follows

```
line 1:64 token recognition error at: ','
```

Let me know how to allow special characters within the expression.

**The grammer file I used**

```
grammar SimpleBoolean;

parse
 : expression EOF
 ;

expression
 : LPAREN expression RPAREN                       #parenExpression
 | NOT expression                                 #notExpression
 | left=expression op=comparator right=expression #comparatorExpression
 | left=expression op=binary right=expression     #binaryExpression
 | bool                                           #boolExpression
 | IDENTIFIER                                     #identifierExpression
 | DECIMAL                                        #decimalExpression
 ;

comparator
 : GT | GE | LT | LE | EQ | NE | IN | NOTIN | STARTSWITH | ENDSWITH | NULL | NOTNULL
 ;

binary
 : AND | OR
 ;

bool
 : TRUE | FALSE
 ;

AND        : 'AND' ;
OR         : 'OR' ;
NOT        : 'NOT';
TRUE       : 'TRUE' ;
FALSE      : 'FALSE' ;
GT         : '>' ;
GE         : '>=' ;
LT         : '<' ;
LE         : '<=' ;
EQ         : '=' ;
NE         : '!=' ;
IN         : 'IN' ;
NOTIN      : 'NOTIN' ;
STARTSWITH : 'STARTSWITH' ;
ENDSWITH   : 'ENDSWITH' ;
NULL       : 'NULL' ;
NOTNULL    : 'NOTNULL' ;
LPAREN     : '(' ;
RPAREN     : ')' ;
DECIMAL    : '-'? [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )? ;
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
WS         : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
```

Modified **EvalVisitor.class**

Added the below lines

```
if (ctx.op.EQ() != null) {
          return this.visit(ctx.left).equals(this.visit(ctx.right));
        }
        else if (ctx.op.IN() != null) {
            String checkVal[] = this.visit(ctx.right).toString().split(",");
            boolean valuePresent = false;
            
            for(String value : checkVal) {
                if(value.equals(this.visit(ctx.left).toString()))
                    valuePresent = true;
            }
            return valuePresent;
        }
```

The **Expression** I passed,

```
ID = ID AND NOT ( comments = comments AND system IN system,admin,developer )
```

Comment: Try putting a '\' (backslash) before the special character.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't pass backslash in the input as it might affect the requirement :(

Comment: Where in your grammar are you trying to accept commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `expression ( ',' expression )+` at the start of the `expression` rule:

```
expression
 : expression ( ',' expression )+ #multipleExpression
 | ...
 ;
```

#### EDIT

After adding the rule above:

```
grammar SimpleBoolean;

parse
 : expression EOF
 ;

expression
 : expression ( ',' expression )+                 #multipleExpression
 | LPAREN expression RPAREN                       #parenExpression
 | NOT expression                                 #notExpression
 | left=expression op=comparator right=expression #comparatorExpression
 | left=expression op=binary right=expression     #binaryExpression
 | bool                                           #boolExpression
 | IDENTIFIER                                     #identifierExpression
 | DECIMAL                                        #decimalExpression
 ;

comparator
 : GT | GE | LT | LE | EQ | NE | IN | NOTIN | STARTSWITH | ENDSWITH | NULL | NOTNULL
 ;

binary
 : AND | OR
 ;

bool
 : TRUE | FALSE
 ;

AND        : 'AND' ;
OR         : 'OR' ;
NOT        : 'NOT';
TRUE       : 'TRUE' ;
FALSE      : 'FALSE' ;
GT         : '>' ;
GE         : '>=' ;
LT         : '<' ;
LE         : '<=' ;
EQ         : '=' ;
NE         : '!=' ;
IN         : 'IN' ;
NOTIN      : 'NOTIN' ;
STARTSWITH : 'STARTSWITH' ;
ENDSWITH   : 'ENDSWITH' ;
NULL       : 'NULL' ;
NOTNULL    : 'NOTNULL' ;
LPAREN     : '(' ;
RPAREN     : ')' ;
DECIMAL    : '-'? [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )? ;
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
WS         : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
```

your example input `9355560 = 9355560 AND NOT ( comments = comments AND system IN system,admin,developer )` gets parsed as follows (without errors!):

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm still getting exception "error(122): Filter.g4:7:0: rule expression: must label all alternatives or none". By the way I would like to pass other special characters as well, as its user input and any values can have special characters in it. Will it be possible for me to provide a grammar for accepting special characters anywhere within a given expression?

Comment: Then you did not do as I suggested :)

Comment: I added the same statement as you mentioned but somehow it was throwing exception. Now it's working fine :)

Comment: You forgot to add `#multipleExpression` at the end of the alternative (which I suggested you do). If it now works, you probably just added it. The error can't miraculously have disappeared :)